# Adding image to page using PIXI

Tags: rendering, pixi.js

I am using a simple example from PIXI

The link to the example is:
http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-js-tutorial-getting-started/

So I changed it a bit and the code in the script tag is now this:

```
<script>
      // create an new instance of a pixi stage
      var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99);
      console.log(stage);
      // create a renderer instance.
      var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300);
      console.log(renderer);
      // add the renderer view element to the DOM
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);


      // create a texture from an image path
      var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("bunny.png");
      // create a new Sprite using the texture
      var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

      // center the sprites anchor point
      bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
      bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;

      // move the sprite t the center of the screen
      bunny.position.x = 200;
      bunny.position.y = 150;

      stage.addChild(bunny);
      renderer.render(stage);

      // requestAnimFrame( animate );

      function animate() {
          requestAnimFrame(animate);
          // render the stage  
          renderer.render(stage);
      }
</script>
```

So instead of using requestAnimFrame( animate );
I am using renderer.render(stage);  instead.

What happens is on FF 32.0.3 it runs fine the bunny.png appears on the screen inside the stage.

On Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m (64-bit), the stage appears but no bunny.

I am also serving up the webpage using Xampp so the path is via a webserver, so no CORS issue using the File path.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

When you call render only once you need to ensure all the assets you need are loaded upfront. Try preloading with the pixi asset manager. cheers!

Comment: Hi Mat thanks for the answer. I guees I was really asking is there a way to not use requestAnimFrame( animate ) in your code. I mean in order to use PIXI is there some point you need to call requestAnimFrame( animate ) otherwise say in this case the bunny never ends up on the stage?

Comment: No worries. Fortunately requestAnimFrame is not required if you don't need it. Basically you need to pre-load the bunny graphic before calling the renderer.render(stage) function. Other wise when you call the render function the bunny texture may not exist yet iyswim?

Answer (score 0):

Try to preload image before calling render

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    renderer.render(stage);
}
img.src = 'bunny.png';
```